# Subversion (SVN) repository server on Mac OSX Snow Leopard, no longer working with Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, svn, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion

I need some major help.  In snow leopard, Subversion was pre-installed.  I had setup a subversion repository and have several coding projects backed up in the repository.  After upgrading to Mountain Lion, i noticed that A.) Subversion was no longer installed and B.) After installing subversion using Xcode, developer tools, command line tools.. It will not work.  My question is what process do i follow to take my pre-existing SVN repository and migrate it to wherever Xcode/Mountain Lion places the subversion repository??  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in upgrading my system, the IP of my machine had changed.  Since i was connecting to the SVN repository using the IP, this no longer worked.  I set the IP correctly and the SVN repository started to work again.